# Symfony 4 - PhpUnit code coverrage report incompleted

Tags: php, symfony, continuous-integration, phpunit

Good afternoon,

I try to realise tests for my application and, when I check the code coverage, PhpUnit returns all tests from all classes, yet no tests from Controller directory. However, in code coverage report, all classes are referred.

*PhpUnit* configuration:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html -->
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="bin/.phpunit/phpunit.xsd"
         backupGlobals="false"
         colors="true"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
>
    <php>
        <ini name="error_reporting" value="-1" />
        <server name="APP_ENV" value="test" force="true" />
        <server name="SHELL_VERBOSITY" value="-1" />
        <server name="SYMFONY_PHPUNIT_REMOVE" value="" />
        <server name="SYMFONY_PHPUNIT_VERSION" value="7.5" />
    </php>

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
            <directory>tests</directory>
            <exclude>tests/Controller/Controller</exclude>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory>src/Controller</directory>
            <directory>src/Data</directory>
            <directory>src/Data</directory>
            <directory>src/Data</directory>
            <directory>src/Entity</directory>
            <directory>src/Entity</directory>
            <directory>src/Service</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>

    <listeners>
        <listener class="Symfony\Bridge\PhpUnit\SymfonyTestsListener" />
    </listeners>
</phpunit>
```

EDIT: "exclude" XML tag is not the problem. I have added this one to prevent a warning when I launch tests because, the "abstract" class ControllerTest is inheritenced by all TestController classes and it does not contains tests.

TestProductController class:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Tests\Controller;

use App\Tests\Controller\Controller\ControllerTest;
use PHPUnit\Framework\ExpectationFailedException;
use SebastianBergmann\RecursionContext\InvalidArgumentException;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceCircularReferenceException;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\InvalidParameterException;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\MissingMandatoryParametersException;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Router;

class TestProjectController extends ControllerTest
{
    /**
     * @var Router
     */
    private $router;

    /**
     * @return void
     *
     * @throws ServiceCircularReferenceException
     * @throws ServiceNotFoundException
     */
    public function setUp(): void
    {
        $this->router = static::$kernel->getContainer()->get('router');
    }

    /**
     * @return void
     *
     * @throws ExpectationFailedException
     * @throws InvalidArgumentException
     * @throws ServiceCircularReferenceException
     * @throws ServiceNotFoundException
     * @throws InvalidParameterException
     * @throws MissingMandatoryParametersException
     * @throws RouteNotFoundException
     */
    public function testProjectListAction()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();

        $client->request('GET', $this->router->generate('project_list'));

        $this->assertEquals(401, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());

        $client->request('GET', $this->router->generate('project_list'), [], [], ['HTTP_Authorization' => self::getToken()]);
    }
}
```

*PhpUnit* code coverage report:

```
Code Coverage Report:    
  2020-08-12 10:16:13    

 Summary:                
  Classes: 55.56% (5/9)  
  Methods: 87.18% (34/39)
  Lines:   93.67% (74/79)

\App\Data\Data::App\Data\Data\AbstractData
  Methods: 100.00% ( 3/ 3)   Lines: 100.00% (  4/  4)
\App\Data\Data::App\Data\Data\User
  Methods: 100.00% ( 7/ 7)   Lines: 100.00% ( 14/ 14)
\App\Data\Exception\Email::App\Data\Exception\Email\EmailInvalidFormatException
  Methods: 100.00% ( 1/ 1)   Lines: 100.00% (  2/  2)
\App\Data\ValueObject::App\Data\ValueObject\Email
  Methods: 100.00% ( 3/ 3)   Lines: 100.00% (  8/  8)
\App\Entity\Entity::App\Entity\Entity\AbstractEntity
  Methods:  80.00% ( 4/ 5)   Lines:  88.89% (  8/  9)
\App\Entity\Entity::App\Entity\Entity\User
  Methods:  87.50% (14/16)   Lines:  93.33% ( 28/ 30)
\App\Service\DTO::App\Service\DTO\UserDTO
  Methods: 100.00% ( 2/ 2)   Lines: 100.00% ( 10/ 10)
```

I expect to have controller classes in code coverage report.

Comment: Maybe because of this line `<exclude>tests/Controller/Controller</exclude>`?

Comment: It is not the problem, I have set this parameter because this directory contains a not testatable file (ControllerTest) and prevent a warning when I execute PhpUnit. This directory has been used by only this file, not by the others TestController classes.